# Formula for finding matching values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in excel that looks like this:

```
State   Member  DOL
MO      LLC     1/1/2017
MO      LLC     1/1/2017
MO      TC      1/1/2017
IL      TC      1/2/2017
IL      LLC     1/1/2017
```

I am trying to use conditional formatting to highlight the whole row for any rows that have the same State, Member, and DOL value.  In three seperate columns I am using a CountIf formula to find how many times each value is being used for each column: Example(`=countif($A$1:$A$10,A1)`).  This is so that I can identify which rows have duplicates for each individual column. So in the above example my new table will look like this:

```
State   Member  DOL
3       3       4
3       3       4
3       2       4
2       2       1
2       3       4
```

I can't figure out what kind of formula I should use next to identify which rows are duplicates.  In the example I showed, the first two rows should be the only ones highlighted because they are the only ones that have the same value for all three columns. Originally I thought that as long as all three columns have a value > than 1, then it's a duplicate.  However, row's 3 and 5 in my example have duplicate values in each column, but the row itself is never actually a full duplicate.  In the end, I would like some kind of formula that will give me this result in a column:

```
Is Duplicate
1
1
0
0
0
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Use countifs() with an s it will allow to compare all three columns at once.

Comment: One way would be to user a helper column and concatenate all of the other fields for that row together.  Then use Excel's built in Conditional Formatting rule to highlight duplicate values (selecting the whole concatenated helper column when setting up the rule).

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks, I can't believe I didn't think about just doing that.  I was trying to make it much more complicated than it needed to be.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the answer..(for the benefit of the future readers.. & to remove this question from "unanswered" list) ?